# Binding of data in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, sapui5

I have a design something like the below picture (see attached pic).
[image]
And the model is something like this:-

```
 {
  "Approvers": [
    {
      "AFE_ID": "DV-101007600DD",
      "AFE_NAME": "San Andreas 1",
      "COST_CENTER": "101007600",
      "LOCATION": "Midland",
      "VERSION": "Revised",
      "DEADLINE": "15th May 2020",
      "ACTION": "Approve/Reject",
      "STATUS": "Completed",
      "WBS_ID": "WBS Element 1",
      "CREATED_BY": "James Edwin",
      "CREATED_ON": "22-04-2020",
      "OWNER": "Dri Mathews",
      "LEVEL": {
        "LEVEL1": [
          {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "Sentra",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
            "LEVEL_ID": 1
          },
          {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "axis",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
            "LEVEL_ID": 1
          }
        ],
        "LEVEL2": [
          {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "bill",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020"
          },
          {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "oilp",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to bind in a way that two boxes should get created based on the levels and each of these boxes should have the data as per the json i.e LEVEL 1 and LEVEL2 data in each of those boxes. In the code below i have binded the Grid controller for Level which creates two boxes but when i try to fill each of these boxes with table content it gets the same content. Please suggest how i can correct this binding?

```
<f:GridContainer id="demoGrid" items="{approversCollection>/Approvers/0/LEVEL}">
                                <f:layout>
                                    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="5rem" columnSize="5rem" gap="1rem"/>
                                </f:layout>
                                <f:layoutS>
                                    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="4rem" columnSize="4rem" gap="0.5rem"/>
                                </f:layoutS>
                                <f:items>
                                    <FlexBox class="columns">
                                        <layoutData>
                                            <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="12"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                        <VBox backgroundDesign="Solid" class="demo">
                                            <VBox>
                                                <Label text="Level" design="Bold" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiMediumMarginBegin"/>
                                            </VBox>
                                            <VBox>
                                                <Table id="idApproversTable" class="demo" inset="false" growing="true"
                                                    items="{ path: 'approversCollection>/Approvers/0/LEVEL/2' }">
                                                    <columns>
                                                        <Column demandPopin="true">
                                                            <Label text="APPROVER NAME" design="Bold"/>
                                                        </Column>
                                                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
                                                            <Label text="DEPARTMENT" design="Bold"/>
                                                        </Column>
                                                        <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
                                                            <Label text="APPROVED ON" design="Bold"/>
                                                        </Column>
                                                    </columns>
                                                    <items>
                                                        <ColumnListItem>
                                                            <cells>
                                                                <Text text="{approversCollection>APPROVER_NAME}"/>
                                                                <Text text="{approversCollection>DEPARTMENT}"/>
                                                                <Text text="{approversCollection>APPROVED_ON}"/>
                                                            </cells>
                                                        </ColumnListItem>
                                                    </items>
                                                </Table>
                                                <layoutData>
                                                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0" backgroundDesign="Solid" styleClass="sapUiTinyMargin"/>
                                                </layoutData>
                                            </VBox>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </FlexBox>
                                </f:items>
                            </f:GridContainer>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the data? Can you change LEVEL to be an Array?

Comment: @Marc - Yes you change that..

Comment: OK then please do exactly that.

Comment: But how will you bind it is my question,

Comment: If `items="{approversCollection>/Approvers/0/LEVEL}` returns an array then this path is correct. Please show your updated JSON model structure.

Comment: "LEVEL": [
        {
          "LEVEL1": [
            {
              "APPROVER_NAME": "Sentra",
              "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
              "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
              "LEVEL_ID": 1
            },
            {
              "APPROVER_NAME": "axis",
              "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
              "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
              "LEVEL_ID": 1
            }
          ]
        }]

Comment: @Marc - This is not working as well, the level get created properly but the table data does not get updated properly for ex. LEVEL 1 data should come in that box and LEVEL 2 data sud come der and that is the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct absolute/relative Paths and modify your Model accordingly:

```
...
"LEVEL":  [
    { "DATA" : [
        {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "Sentra",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
            "LEVEL_ID": 1
        },
        {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "axis",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020",
            "LEVEL_ID": 1
        }
    ]},
    { "DATA" : [
        {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "bill",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020"
        },
        {
            "APPROVER_NAME": "oilp",
            "DEPARTMENT": "Drilling",
            "APPROVED_ON": "23-07-2020"
        }
    ]}
]
...

<f:GridContainer id="demoGrid" items="{approversCollection>/Approvers/0/LEVEL}">
...
    <Table id="idApproversTable" 
        class="demo"
        inset="false" 
        growing="true"
        items="{ path: 'approversCollection>DATA' }">
...
        <Text text="{approversCollection>APPROVER_NAME}"/>
        <Text text="{approversCollection>DEPARTMENT}"/>
        <Text text="{approversCollection>APPROVED_ON}"/>
```

Comment: if i write the json model like this then it will not take the "DATA" array twice, it gets replaced with the recent entry.i need to name one of them as DATA and second one as "DATA2" something like that, otherwise it wont work.  Please suggest how can i correct this. @A.vH

Comment: Did you check the correct data structure?
"Level" is an array of Objects.
Each Object can contains a Property "Data" that is an array of objects

Where as your data structure is:
"Level" is an object that contains properties "Level1"and "Level2" that are  array of objects

Comment: Okay agree my data structure is incorrect; you may change the data as you like but i hope you understand why i want the LEVEL1 as array of objects because there can be more than one Approvers at the backend for a level. However the data structure you have provided is also incorrect. The data you have provided , pls put it in json formatter and see , in the data array you will be able to see only last entry. So yeah the data format i snot correct and i am not sure how the data should this be corrected.

Comment: Take a look at the example https://plnkr.co/edit/b29prxbcLVDXUz3b?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Hey, Yes Thankyou it worked :) , Thanks for all the effort that you have put in this.